# How to add dummy variables Q1, Q2, Q3 based on the month of Date variable (YYYYMMDD)?

Tags: r, date

I want to create 4 dummy variables referring to every quarter as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 which would be dependent on the month of Sales which is in Date format.

Something like this:

```
Date         Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
01/01/2017    1  0  0  0
02/01/2017    0  1  0  0
03/01/2017    0  0  1  0
04/01/2017    0  0  0  1
```

I tried extracting the month of Sales date using month(Date) using lubridate package and then tried to create dummy variables, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 on these lines (not exactly the same code but trying to use this logic to created variables):

```
df$Q1 <- ifelse(month(Date) = *"first month of every quarter"*,1,0)
df$Q2 <- ifelse(month(Date) = *"second month of every quarter"*,1,0)
df$Q3 <- ifelse(month(Date) = *"third month of every quarter"*,1,0)  
df$Q4 <- ifelse(month(Date) = *"fourth month of every quarter"*,1,0)
```

But this method didn't work to get a matrix like mentioned above.

Please help with the same or if there is some smarter way to accomplish this then please let me know.

Comment: The meaning of the `Qx` variable is unclear to me. In the expected result there are four variables `Q1` to `Q4` but only three in the code snippet.

Comment: @UweBlock: Not creating Q4 variable because of degree of freedom. 4 quarters in an year, using only 3 in modelling creation.

Comment: So, you want to create only three variables but your questions starts with *I want to create 4 dummy variables referring to every quarter as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4*. And your matrix shows four columns. This is still confusing. However, there are different answers (mine contains two different approaches). Perhaps, you can indicate which of the answers are returning the expected result, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: The question wasn't stated clearly and OP's intent were interpreted differently. Now, the OP has clarified that he was after the second answer below.

#### Answer 1

The questions starts with the sentence: *I want to create 4 dummy variables referring to every quarter as Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4 which would be dependent on the month of Sales which is in Date format* plus a sample matrix. This can be interpreted that the OP wants to determine the quarter a given date belongs to and display this "graphically" in a wide format.

This can be achieved using the `dcast()` function to reshape and the `quarter()`function from `lubridate`:

```
# create sample data
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 4, by = "3 months"))
# reshape
data.table::dcast(DF, Date ~ paste0("Q", lubridate::quarter(DF$Date)), length, 
                  value.var = "Date")
```

> ```
>         Date Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
> 1 2017-01-01  1  0  0  0
> 2 2017-04-01  0  1  0  0
> 3 2017-07-01  0  0  1  0
> 4 2017-10-01  0  0  0  1
> ```

The `dcast()` function is available from two packages: `reshape2` and `data.table`.

#### Answer 2

In case the OP is asking for the number of the month *within* each quarter, i.e., 1st month, 2nd month, or 3rd month, here is an alternative solution which uses the `toOrdinal` package to convert cardinal numbers to ordinal numbers

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), length.out = 12, by = "1 months"))
month_in_quarter <- function(x) 
  sprintf("%s_M_in_Qtr", sapply((month(x) - 1) %% 3 + 1, toOrdinal::toOrdinal))
data.table::dcast(DF, Date ~ month_in_quarter(Date), length, value.var = "Date")
```

> ```
>          Date 1st_M_in_Qtr 2nd_M_in_Qtr 3rd_M_in_Qtr
> 1  2017-01-01            1            0            0
> 2  2017-02-01            0            1            0
> 3  2017-03-01            0            0            1
> 4  2017-04-01            1            0            0
> 5  2017-05-01            0            1            0
> 6  2017-06-01            0            0            1
> 7  2017-07-01            1            0            0
> 8  2017-08-01            0            1            0
> 9  2017-09-01            0            0            1
> 10 2017-10-01            1            0            0
> 11 2017-11-01            0            1            0
> 12 2017-12-01            0            0            1
> ```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for. The goal is to get indicator of the position of the month *within* each quarter, so for January through December, you'd have `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,31,2,3)` and build the indicators off of that.

Comment: @lmo Yes, I admit that this might be the case. However, the matrix shown in the question would be greatly misleading, then.

Comment: True. That matrix is confusing whatever interpretation one has. Also, OP is not consistent in expressing what they want. It may be a two part question... I supposed I focused on the second part "Now I want to create dummy variables, Q1, Q2, Q3 as" then the `ifelse` pseudo code. It is not clear whether they accomplished their first goal, which is what your answer focuses on.

Comment: Thanks @UweBlock and everyone else. I know the question was not stated clearly, but really appreciate the help! Second part of this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)    
df1 %>%
  mutate(Qs = paste0("Q", month(mdy(Date))), ind = 1) %>%        
  spread(Qs, ind, fill = 0)
#       Date Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4
#1 01/01/2017  1  0  0  0
#2 02/01/2017  0  1  0  0
#3 03/01/2017  0  0  1  0
#4 04/01/2017  0  0  0  1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2017", "02/01/2017", "03/01/2017", 
 "04/01/2017")), .Names = "Date", row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This isn't what OP is asking for. The goal is to get indicator of the position of the month *within* each quarter, so for January through December, you'd have `c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)` and build the indicators off of that.

Comment: @lmo Sorry, I thought it was the quarterly data they want. Thanks, corrected

Comment: On further reading, it is not entirely clear. It seems like they may be asking 2 questions. uwe-block has asked them for clarification, but no response as of yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method using factors and `model.matrix`. The trickiest part is in properly setting up the month of the quarter factor variables.

Assuming we start out with a character vector as below. First, convert to a Date vector.

```
dates<- as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

Now, put this into a data.frame and add a Quarter variable using `factor`.

```
dat <- data.frame(Date=dates,
                  mnthQrtr=factor(as.integer(format(dates, "%m")) %% 3,
                                  levels=c(1:2, 0), labels=c(paste0("MQ", c(1:3)))))
```

Here, the modulus operator returns values 0 through 3 where 3 corresponds to the fourth month in the quarter, so the levels argument must account for this.

Now, create the binary variables with `model.matrix` and with tack them on with `cbind`.

```
dat <- cbind(dat, model.matrix(~mnthQrtr-1, dat))
```

This returns

```
dat
        Date mnthQrtr mnthQrtrMQ1 mnthQrtrMQ2 mnthQrtrMQ3
1 2017-01-01      MQ1           1           0           0
2 2017-02-01      MQ2           0           1           0
3 2017-03-01      MQ3           0           0           1
4 2017-04-01      MQ1           1           0           0
```

**Data**

```
dates <- c("01/01/2017", "02/01/2017", "03/01/2017", "04/01/2017")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option using the great `dummies` package to create dummy variables. Just involves creating a 'Quarter' column using the  `zoo`   package.

Load packages:

```
require(dummies)
require(zoo)
```

Create some test data:

```
df<-data.frame(date =seq(as.Date("2017/1/1"), as.Date("2017/4/1"), "months"))
```

Create new Quarter column saying which quarter a date falls in:

```
df$Quarter<-format(as.yearqtr(df$date), "Q%q")
```

Create dummy variables for categorical variables:

```
df<-dummy.data.frame(df, sep="_")
```

Adjust column names to align with question:

```
colnames(df)<-gsub("Quarter_", "", colnames(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using 'dt' and 'get_dummies':**

**Steps:**

1. Use 'dt.quarter' on the column that has the dates.
2. Use 'get_dummies' on the column created in step 1.

**Example:**

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = '2017', periods = 4, freq = 'Q'), columns = ['Dates'])
```

1. New Column

```
df['Quarter'] = df['Dates'].dt.quarter
```

2. Dummies

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['Quarter'])
```